# How to save the selected item in dropdown option, and retrieve that data during edit using thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am able to save book and author to the database. While editing the content of the entry(Book title, genre, and author), I loose the author's part. In the Edit page, the list of author is rendered using dropdown. The idea is that a specific author has to be selected until the user changed it.

here are the controller and the template for Book.

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"/edit", "/edit/{id}"})
public String editBookById(Model model, @PathVariable("id")
                           Optional<Long>id)
        throws NotFoundException
{
    if (id.isPresent()) {
        Optional<Book> response = bookRepository.findById(id.get());
        if(!response.isPresent()){
            throw new NotFoundException("Book not found.");
            // return "not-found";
        }

        Book book = response.get();

        model.addAttribute("book", book);
      } else {
        model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
    }
    model.addAttribute("authors", authorRepository.findAll());
    return "books/add-edit";
}
```

Template:

```
<form action="@/books/edit" th:object="${book}" method='POST'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Select Authors:</td>
      <td>
        <select id="authorsList" name="authors" field="*{author}"><!---1,2,3,4,5--><!---the secret-->
        <!--<option value="Author">Author</option>-->
          <option th:each="author :${authors}"
                  th:value="${author.firstName}"
                  th:text="${author.firstName}+' '+${author.id}"
                  th:selected="${author}">
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement editing of a form, you need to implement a `GetMapping` and a `PostMapping` (Both are meta-annotations of `RequestMapping`).

When the browser shows the form first, it does a GET. The method in the controller to support that should be something like:

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String showEditForm(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
  Book book = bookRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow( ()-> new NotFoundException("Book not found. Id: " + id));

  model.addAttribute("book", book);
  model.addAttribute("authors", authorRepository.findAll());
  return "books/add-edit";
}
```

When the form is submitted, a POST happens, so you need a `@PostMapping`. Something like:

```
@PostMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String doEditBook(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("book") Book book, BindingResults bindingResults, Model model) {
  if(bindingResults.hasErrors()) {
    model.addAttribute("authors", authorRepository.findAll());
    return "books/add-edit"
  }

  // save book updates in db here
  bookService.updateBook(book);

  return "redirect:/books";
}
```

However, it is usually a bad idea to use your `Book` entity directly in the form. It is better to create a DTO, something like `EditBookFormData` that directly maps to the form fields:

```
public class EditBookFormData {

  private Long id; // this is the id of the book itself
  private Long authorId;
  // other fields here

  public static EditBookFormData fromBook(Book book) {
    // create a new EditBookFormData instance here and populate the fields
  }
}
```

The updated `GetMapping` becomes:

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String showEditForm(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
  Book book = bookRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow( ()-> new NotFoundException("Book not found. Id: " + id));

  model.addAttribute("book", EditBookFormData.fromBook(book));
  model.addAttribute("authors", authorRepository.findAll());
  return "books/add-edit";
}
```

The POST becomes:

```
@PostMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String doEditBook(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("book") EditBookFormData formData, BindingResults bindingResults, Model model) {
  if(bindingResults.hasErrors()) {
    model.addAttribute("authors", authorRepository.findAll());
    return "books/add-edit"
  }

  // save book updates in db here
  bookService.updateBook(formData);

  return "redirect:/books";
}
```

And the template:

```
<form action="@/books/edit" th:object="${book}" method='POST'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Select Authors:</td>
      <td>
        <select id="authorsList" name="authors" th:field="*{authorId}">
          <option th:each="author :${authors}"
                  th:value="${author.id}"
                  th:text="${author.firstName}+' '+${author.lastName}">
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```